# Using image path as div background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code i found on another post, showing how to replace a image with divs, while keeping the attributes of the image.
i want the image source to be background-image of the div that is replacing it..

The code i found is

```
$('.produkt_billede > img').each(function(){
    $div = $('<div>').html($(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).replaceWith($div);
});
```

My desired result is:

```
<div style="background-image: url('image.png');" class="something"></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would need to do is define the appropriate attributes of the `<div>` when you create it:

```
$('.produkt_billede > img').each(function(){
    var path_to__image = $(this).attr('src');
    $div = $('<div>', {
      'style': 'background-image: url("'+ path_to__image +'");',
      'class': 'something'
    });
    $(this).replaceWith($div);
});
```

When creating an element, the second parameter can be an object defining the new attributes for it. In this case, I'm defining the `style` and `class` attributes; You can add more if you require.

Comment: Thanks alot, makes sense .. this worked .. but i cant check it untill in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.produkt_billede > img').each(function(){
    $div = $('<div>').css({'background-image': "url(" + $(this).attr('src') + ")"}).addClass("something");
    $(this).replaceWith($div);
});
```

I think this should do it.

Please note that you need to set the div and height of the resulting div either through css or js or it will collapse to 0 and 0 as it doesn't containe anything, rendering your div invisible: http://jsfiddle.net/t1L43vxr/1/